# Add incremental counter for repeating feature subsets in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, duplicates

Suppose I have the following table:

| id | name | mail | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Sta | sta@example.com | 11.11.22 |
| 2 | Danny | dany@example.com | 11.11.22 |
| 3 | Elle | elle@example.com | 11.11.22 |
| 4 | Elle | falsemail@example.com | 11.11.22 |
| 5 | Elle | elle@example.com | 12.11.22 |

What is the best way to create an incremental counter for repeating observations for the feature subset [name, date]?

Desired output:

| id | name | mail | date | counter |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Sta | sta@example.com | 11.11.22 | 1 |
| 2 | Danny | dany@example.com | 11.11.22 | 1 |
| 3 | Elle | elle@example.com | 11.11.22 | 1 |
| 4 | Elle | falsemail@example.com | 11.11.22 | 2 |
| 5 | Elle | elle@example.com | 12.11.22 | 1 |

Edit: The table itself is sorted correctly and the duplicates appear after each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df['counter'] = df.groupby(['name', 'date']).cumcount() + 1 
df
   id   name                   mail        date  counter
0  1    Sta         sta@example.com   11.11.22         1
1  2   Danny       dany@example.com   11.11.22         1
2  3   Elle        elle@example.com   11.11.22         1
3  4   Elle   falsemail@example.com   11.11.22         2
4  5   Elle        elle@example.com   12.11.22         1
```